# Let $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x^3,x\in[-1,1].$ Then which of the following are true?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x^3,x\in[-1,1].$ Then which of the following are true?

(A) $W(f,g)(x)=0, x\in [-1,1]$

(B) $f$ and $g$ are linearly dependent.

(C) $f$ and $g$ are the linearly independent solution of some second order differential equation.

(D) $W\neq 0$ for  some $x\in [-1,1]$.

Solution:-

(A)$ W(f,g)(x)=x^4$. So, (1) is false. But in the answer key, they have given to be true.
(B) Both are linearly independent. So, (B) is false.

(C)Consider $x^2y''-4xy'+6y=0$, It has $f,g $ are solutions.

(D) $W(f,g)=x^4$ at $x=1$ $W(f,g)=1. $

Hence (C0 and $(D)$ are true. But answer key given to be $(A)$ and $(C)$ are true. Can you help me?

Comment: The "answers at the back of the book" are not always correct.